# Too many arguments when reading from variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script which will toggle my trackpad activity every time it is run. It is as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

zero=0;

if [ ! -f "/tmp/touchpadON.dat"  ]; then 
    T=0                                  
    xinput disable 12
    echo no file found
else
    T='cat /tmp/touchpadON.dat'
    if [ $T -eq $zero ]  # ERROR here, too many arguments.
    then
    T=1
    xinput disable 12
    echo diabling trackpad

    else
    T=0
    xinput enable 12
    echo enabling trackpad
    fi

fi

echo $T

echo "${T}" > /tmp/touchpadON.dat
```

When I try to run this script, I gen an error on line 11 telling me I have too many arguments. How do I fix this?

Comment: What's in /tmp/touchpadON.dat?  You must be getting more than one word from there and that's what is causing the issue.

Comment: Try T=$(cat file.dat)

Comment: You've got a *lot* of bugs here. http://shellcheck.net/ will identify many of them for you -- make a habit of fixing everything it finds before asking a question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: By the way, let me suggest that putting `0` as a constant in a variable is a really bad idea. If you copy-and-paste code that assumes that variable is set into a script that doesn't set it, anyone debugging that will be doing a lot of head scratching -- and it doesn't really improve readability over just hardcoding `0`. Moreover, using `$zero` introduces the chance that the contents of the variable *could be something other than `0`*, whereas a constant `0` is only ever exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `T=$(cat file.dat)`.
Your way you have not the content of the file but just the command.

Comment: Might be, I haven't tried ;). At least will get the value I suppose it's in the file he wants to read, and not just printing the string as he's doing now. He will check ;) Thanks for the comment and to point that out!

Comment: I get it now. His code has single quotes instead of back quotes.  Your solution will work as long as file.dat doesn't result in more than one word.

Comment: Yes sure, it's just going to work in that case! I assumed, but I don't know, will see!

Comment: If you add quotes on `[ $T -eq 0 ]`, making it `[ "$T" -eq 0 ]`, then we won't get a too-many-arguments case even if the file doesn't contain the right number of words. And with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, consider `$(<file.dat)`, which is more efficient (doesn't require starting a copy of an external `/bin/cat` program, but is instead handled by the shell internally).

Comment: Of course, at that point, you could write `if (( T == 0 )); then ...`, and get better readability too.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if [ $T -eq $zero ]
```

to

```
if [ $T -eq "$zero" ]
```

and try.

---

You can write your if statement better this way:

```
if [[ $T == $zero ]]
```

Refer to the Bash manual on [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs).

Comment: `[ "$T" -eq "$zero" ]` and `[[ $T == $zero ]]` are very different things -- the former is a numeric comparison, the latter a string comparison. `000` will be `-eq` to `0`, but not `=` to `0`.

Comment: (As an aside: `==` is valid inside `[[ ]]`, but since folks having `==` in their finger-memory tend to also use it inside `[ ]`, where it [*isn't* guaranteed to be valid](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), I tend to suggest using `=` in examples consistently).